# Google Play Billing Security: How to prove a purchase token belongs to a specific user without developerPayload field?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I've notice that the latest tutorial for Google Play Billing removed content about `developerPayload` field when user make purchases.

According to the tutorial, [backend server verification relies on an **account credential** passed by client application.](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#Verify-purchase) But this isn't secure when user is under a hacked network.

Comment: You don't seem to have a question here, just statements. That might explain why you have no answers.